# game renderer thread backtrace with no symbols on linux

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I have a game application running in linux. We are a gaming company. I am having this random crash that occurs like once in 24-48 hours. The last time it occurred I tried to see the backtrace of the thread where it crashed, however gdb showed that the stack was corrupted with no symbols.
Now, when I run the game and interrupt the gdb, sometimes I am able to see function call stack for this thread but most of the times I do not see any symbols.The thread is a renderer thread.
Some of the game libraries we are using is proprietary third party with no debugging symbols. So I was wondering could it be that the renderer thread call stack is deep(various calls within library) into these libraries without symbols and so I do not get to see the call stack ? If that is true, how can I fix this ? 
If not, any idea what could be the cause.

Comment: It is impossible to provide a useful answer without much more details: what CPU you are running on? What version of GDB? What is the *actual* output from `bt` and `info proc maps`? Etc.

Comment: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6 , Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4100E CPU @ 2.40GHz

    (gdb) bt
    #0  0x9ea8a702 in ?? ()
    Cannot access memory at address 0x3f340004

Comment: the game just crashed in the morning.
I did a bt and got

`(gdb) bt
#0  0x9f488882 in ?? ()`

Also, did a 

`info proc mappings` and for the address above in `bt` I found the following:
`0x9f488000 0x9f48a000     0x2000        0x0 /tmp/glyFI8DP (deleted)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> (gdb) bt
> #0 0x9f488882 in ?? ()
> ```
>
> Also, did a info proc mappings and for the address above in bt I found the following:
>
> ```
> 0x9f488000 0x9f48a000 0x2000 0x0 /tmp/glyFI8DP (deleted)
> ```

This means that your third-party library is using just-in-time compilation to generate some code, mmap it into your process, and deletes it.

On x86_64, GDB needs unwind descriptors to unwind the stack, but it can't get them from the deleted file, so you get no stack trace.

You have a few options:

- contact the third-party developers and ask them "how can we get stack traces in this situation?"
- dump the contents of the region with GDB `dump` command:

  `(gdb) dump /tmp/gly.so 0x9f488000 0x9f48a000`

  If you are lucky, the resulting binary would actually be an ELF (it doesn't have to be), and may have symbols and unwind descriptors in it. Use `readelf --all /tmp/gly.so` to look inside.

  If it is an ELF file, you can let GDB know that that's what's mapped at `0x9f488000`. You'll need to find the address (`$tstart` below) of `.text` section in it (should be in `readelf` output), then:

  `(gdb) add-symbol-file /tmp/gly.so 0x9f488000+$tstart`

Comment: I dumped the memory. but it is not an elf file. I used the following commands.

    `dump memory /tmp/gly.so 0x9f488000 0x9f48a000`

    `readelf -all /tmp/gly.so`
    `readelf: Error: Not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start`

Comment: could you please tell me how did you derive that it is just in time compilation. I would like to learn it.